# MetaData Error in a SSIS Package

Tags: ssis

I have an package where i load csv source files into table. I have two typs of source files, employee and employeedetails.

1. **For example Employee csv file has 4 columns eid, ename, designation,
   age.**
2. **Employeedetails csv file has 6 columns eid, ename, designation, age,
       depatname, deptid**.
3. **My destination table has eid, ename, designation, age, depatname,
       deptid.**

Now, i want to load this 2 files based on file type variable in my Variables collection. I have completed that part also.

So instead of using 2 Dataflow tasks, i used only one. My DFT has following transformations inside it.

**RawFileSource

|

Derived column Transformation

|

Oledb Destination table**

In Control Flow i have used Execute Package Task whcih calls Child package when i give filetype as Employee, it runs Employee Package where it takes employee CSV file and loads it into rawfile destination.

If i select File type as Employeedetails, it runs EmployeeDetails Package where it takes employeeDetails CSV file and loads it into rawfile destination.

now i take this raw file and need to load it into destination table. Foe one file am able to load, when i load the second file be it either Employee file or EmployeeDetails file, metadata problem occurs.

Because of this i need to go to Package and change each and every transformation.

I tried keeping validate External Meta data value to false for all the transformations and at package level also.

How to over come this problem and load my two files.

Comment: Take a peek at my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686785/ssis-pkg-with-flat-file-connection-with-fewer-columns-will-fail/10696025#10696025 I think you're running into the same problem

Comment: Use two different dataflows to load into two different staging tables, then use a stored procedure to transform as required and load into the final table. Can you summarise what you're actually tryng to do at the start of the question rather than launching into proposed solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since the two files have different columns, you need two data flows. You could have a step in the control flow that choses the correct one based on the filename you send in as a varaiable.

But since the details file has all the columns of the employees file, why don't you just process that one and ignore the other?

Comment: hi, Both the input files data varies. So i cant ignore any of the file. Any way i'll try using that 2 dfts approach. But if i use 2 DFT's i load data into RAw File deatination and where up on i load it into destination table. i think there also metadata prob occurs.